SSRS...Using a Lookup function but only returns the first record value
I am pulling my hair out over this! I have an SSRS report. No grouping on it. I added a dataset from one SQL server (which is a stored procedure). The other data set I added is embedded in the text. I have run both queries separately and they work correctly. My issue is it is only pulling the FIRST record on the report!  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with SSRS v. 16
I've done this before without any issues. Any ideas why this would be happening? I've dropped the report and re-created it with no luck. Using a table and just added the expression into a Text placeholder in one of the columns. I'm out of ideas!
I have changed the sorting on both queries to match up.. no luck.

Your problem is not clearly explained. Please edit your question and show the steps to recreate the problem. Show samples of data from both datasets (as text) and show you report design. Include any relevant expressions.
